# Parallel sort and array sort not giving equal output

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I am trying to insertion-sort (some modification) an array using threads. My problem is that sometimes after I sort, I get that `para_array`  and `arraysort` are equal, sometimes not. The checking where the numbers are not equal I get something like this:

```
 99940 and 99941
 99938 and 99940
 99935 and 99938
 99934 and 99935
 99932 and 99934
```

where `para_array` has the left values and `arraysort` has the right

I fill both the array before sorting with random(7363), one random for each so they have the same values.

I have to sort the `k` first numbers of the array, so what I do is I serially sort the `k` first like this:

```
 //sort the k first wher 0 is largest number and k-1 is lowest
 for (int i = 1; i < k; i++) {
      int check = para_array[i];
      int prev = i - 1;
      while (prev >= 0 && para_array[prev] < check) {
        para_array[prev + 1] = para_array[prev];
        previous_element--;
      }
      para_array[prev + 1] = check;
    }
```

I then start the threads. I have a list of threads to run:

```
  for (Thread t : threads) {
    t.start();
  }
```

My thread:

```
 public SortingThread(int[] arr, int start, int end, int k, Object lock) {
  this.arr = arr;
  this.start = start;
  this.end = end;
  this.k = k;
  this.lock = lock;
}

@Override
public void run() {
  for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
    //whill try to find a larger value in its own segment than k-2 if found sort it
    synchronized (lock) {
      if (arr[i] > arr[k - 1]) {
        int set_correct = arr[i];
        int j = k - 2;
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] < set_correct) {
          
          arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
          
          j--;
        }
        
        arr[j + 1] = set_correct;
        }
      }
    
  }

}
```

The threads are created like this:

```
  // Create and start all the threads
  for (int i = 0; i < number_of_cores; i++) {
    int start = i * portionSize;
    int end = Math.min((i + 1) * portionSize, n);

    threads.add(new SortingThread(para_array, start, end, k,locks.get(i)));
  }
```

I then sort the other array with `array.sort()` and make it in decreasing order, then I check the *k* first values for both.

Comment: Update, I see now that sometimes the para_array has two of the same elements after eachothr and the arraysort does not, and othertimes it is the opposite

Comment: Sorting the first `k` elements does not change which elements are in that section of the array.  But if any of the `k` largest elements do not start among the first `k` elements overall, then sorting the whole array (decreasing) *does* change which elements are among the first `k`.  It's not surprising, then, that you sometimes observe different results from the two approaches you describe.

Comment: Or if that's not what you're actually doing then please clarify.

Comment: @JohnBollinger im not sure if i understood you, but i do not need to sort the whole array just the first k, which is done by the for loop w/o threads, then when wanting to find if the rest of array has larger number that the ones in the k-first we let the threads just go thorugh their segment and checks and the just insert it to the k-first

Comment: My comment is about how you prepare the other array for comparison: "I then sort the other array with `array.sort()` and make it in decreasing order".  As written, that seems to say that you sort the *whole* other array (more than `k` elements), which is the wrong thing to do for your comparison if the other sort (was supposed to have) sorted only the first `k` elements of its array.

Comment: @JohnBollinger im sorry for misunderstanding, the way i do the arraysort is i first make every number in the array negativ, after that i use array.sort(arraysort) after that i make every number positive. But if the whole array is sorted, shouldent the k first also be sorted correctly?

Comment: Yes, that would make the first `k` sorted correctly relative to each other, but you're missing the point.  The first `k` of the result are likely not *the same* first `k`. Consider a trivial example: The initial array is `{ 2, 7, 3 }` and `k` is 1.  If you sort just the first 1 element of that, by any correct algorithm, then the result is `{ 2, 7, 3 }`.  If you sort the the whole array then the result is `{ 7, 3, 2 }`.  The first `k` (1) elements of these two results do not agree.

Comment: ´The first k of the result are likely not the same first k´ what you mean with this, are you now comparing the para_array with arraysort, if so shouldent be if the numbers and k is the same for both, if you talk about the segment of each thread, the first k are not the same probably, but why is that important, they will go through the whole segment and just compare it to the k of the para_array. i see that i have messed up the array names in the code which would make this confusing, when creating a thread we should pass in para_array

Comment: But even if you corrected your checking strategy, your parallel sort is not correct. Consider the serial version: each iteration of the outer loop depends on the invariant that the leading `i` elements of the array are already in sorted order relative to each other. That is achieved by the in-order operation of the previous `i-1` outer-loop iterations.  If you just split the outer-loop iterations among multiple threads, you do not ensure the needed order of those outer-loop iterations.  If you add enough synchronization to ensure that, then it makes the sort effectively serial.

Comment: i would consider writing parallel mergesort algorithm instead. divide & conquer algorithms are easier to split into more or less independent tasks for threads.

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions, i am learning about parallel and am just trying my best to try it here, but try the others also

Comment: Letting each thread synchronize on a different object has no effect at all. This is broken.

Comment: @Holger I thought you had to synchronize when trying to change a value everyone has access to?

Comment: @Holger could you help me figure out why this wont work.

Comment: I already told you. Your code is not thread safe. There might be more issues, but this code is too complicated to see everything at a glance, especially as it is incomplete. It’s not a useful approach anyway. Read about Quicksort or MergeSort. These are algorithms you can understand and have a natural way of extending them to parallel processing.